# Taking prompt input to look up in object giving me undefined

Tags: javascript

```
const Max = {
    firstName: "Max",
    job: "IT-Support",
    hasdriverlicense: false,
    age: 24
};

const Frank= {
    firstName: "Frank",
    job: "Grafikdesigner",
    hasdriverlicense: true,
    age: 23
};

const input = prompt("Whos information you need?");

    console.log(input.firstName + " is a " + input.age + " years old " + input.job
        + " and " + (input.hasdriverlicense ? " has " : " has no ") + "driving license");
```

What am I doing wrong? Or how can I solve that issue? Thanks in advance!

Comment: How is `input` getting those(firstName, age, job, etc.) attributes?

Comment: I have all informations in a object prepared. I just want to submit a name, and get those informations

Comment: Please post all the code and provide more information in the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const Max = {
    firstName: "Max",
    job: "IT-Support",
    hasdriverlicense: false,
    age: 24
};

const Frank= {
    firstName: "Frank",
    job: "Grafikdesigner",
    hasdriverlicense: true,
    age: 23
};

const input = prompt("Whos information you need?");
let profile = null;

switch(input){
 case "Frank": profile = Frank; break;
 case "Max": profile = Max; break;
 default: console.log("Nothing Found!");
}

if(profile != null){
    console.log(profile.firstName + " is a " + profile.age + " years old " + profile.job
        + " and " + (profile.hasdriverlicense ? " has " : " has no ") + "driving license");
}
```